# Does Drupal node_load lock the Node and Related Fields?

Tags: drupal, drupal-nodes, drupal-database

I'm in Drupal 7 and implementing custom script inside Drupal Root folder. Then i'm trying to call-up a node with `node_load(1234)` and then `node_save($node)`. Between this two methods, i'm trying to `DELETE` some records (some DB Rows). But i can not make it work in any way i found.

The scenario is like:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
..
.. Step 1. Some node updates like: $node->title = "New Title!";
.. Step 2. Some row DELETIONS
..
node_save($node);
```

Then `Step 2.` is **NOT WORKING**.
`Step 2.` may include Row Deletion Methods like:

```
$deleted_row = db_delete('some_table')
          ->condition('nid', $nid)
          ->execute();
[or]
db_query("DELETE FROM {some_table} WHERE nid = %d", $nid);
```

So my questions are:

- Is Drupal `node_load` locking the loaded `node` and all its related
  fields (rows) before it release back by `node_save` ?
- Is there any possible way to DELETE a Simple DB Row (after `node_load` is called) ?

Any suggestion please.

Comment: One of those example statements is from Drupal 6 and one from Drupal 7...which are you using?

Comment: I mentioned `[or]`. So which one you think will solve the problem?

Comment: the first if you use drupal7 , the second if you use drupal6

Comment: I know it, so do you have real answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one answered. But i found it by myself that the answer is "no, it doesn't lock".